# How to map a path to the corresponding /dev file in UNIX - C++?

Tags: c++, unix, path, device

I'm trying to get the corresponding `/dev` file given a path name, kind of like `df` command

I currently use this command, but I'd rather not use `system()` function or system-specific commands.

Here's the current code :

```
const string PathStr (Path); // Path is input value

// get the /dev/* files
string Cmd ("df 2> /dev/null | grep /dev | awk '{print $1, $6}'");

FILE * Pipe = popen (Cmd.c_str(), "r");
if (!Pipe)
{
    errorLog("Cannot execute command : \"" + Cmd + '"');
    return string();
}

char Buf [BufSz];
stringstream sstr;
while (!feof(Pipe))
{
    if (fgets(Buf, BufSz, Pipe))
        sstr << Buf;
}
pclose(Pipe);

// get the actual /dev file
pair<string, string> DiskPaths;
while (!sstr.eof())
{
    string Dev, MountPoint;
    sstr >> Dev >> MountPoint;
    if (string::npos != PathStr.find(MountPoint) &&
        MountPoint.size() > DiskPaths.second.size())
        DiskPaths = make_pair(Dev, MountPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `system()` and parsing the output may well be the more reliable and portable way to do what you are trying to do, because the `df` command may use all sorts of system-dependant tricks to resolve device numbers to names in `/dev` which you'd have to implement yourself otherwise.

You can easily get the device NUMBER of the filesystem on which a file is located: it's the `st_dev` field of the `stat()` structure. But how to find what file in `/dev` goes with that number is left as an exercise for the `df` command. In particular, remember that not every filesystem is mounted from a file in `/dev`: think NFS, and special filesystems like `/proc`.

Here are some other things you can do:

- Scan every file in `/dev` looking for a block device whose `st_rdev` is the same number
- Parse the table of mounted filesystem (`/etc/mtab` or `/etc/mnttab`, it's system-dependant) looking for a mount prefix that looks like it might be a parent of the pathname you're interested in.

Comment: Right, the `stat()` trick seems to do the thing but it's much simpler to keep using `df`. Thus, `df` reads `/etc/mtab` file too, but I guess it's much reliable than to do it myself.